# Can anyone help me identify the Japanese font on the cover of this book?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

[image]
I am looking for the font that is used on the cover of the book in the image, does anyone know it? I am not even sure if such a font exists, it might be calligraphy but any answer is much appreciated.

Comment: That appears to be Chinese rather than Japanese.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be custom art. The cover art designer [posted about their illustration](https://heishing.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/%e6%95%99%e6%88%91%e5%a6%82%e4%bd%95%e6%b4%bb%e5%87%ba%e6%99%82%e4%bb%a3%e7%9a%84%e7%9f%9b%e7%9b%be%ef%bc%9f/#comment-2011) on their blog:

> 而書封上的字體方面，我則以「矛盾」為概念，重新設計「活出時代的矛盾」的書名字體，以姚體作基礎，橫幼豎粗，修長的字形，點撇乾淨利落，如刀削，有攻擊性，亦富文革「口號式」的時代感。

I don't actually read Chinese (only Japanese), but it seems to suggest that the (Chinese) title of the book 活出時代的矛盾 that appears also as part of the English cover was a custom design based off the [方正姚体 font](http://www.foundertype.com/index.php/FontInfo/index.html?id=170)*. In this font, the title would look as follows (missing one character from the free preview):

[image]

<sub>* or a font with a similar name — they only say 姚體 (=姚体) in their post</sub>

Comment: That’s correct. A loose translation: “For the font used on the cover, though, I used the word 矛盾 [contradiction] as concept, designing the characters for the title based on the 姚体 [Yaoti] font. I made it a tall, slender font with thin horizontal lines, thick vertical lines, and nimble 点 [dots] and 撇 [left-slanting downward lines]—a font that looks like it was peeled off with a knife, an aggressive font full of the zeitgeist of Cultural Revolution slogans”.